# How to make externalized properties file available to spring boot integration tests?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, properties, properties-file

I am developing an application using Spring Boot. I have an externalized properties file on file system. Its location is stored in an environment variable as below--

> export props=file://Path-to-file-on-filesystem/file.properties

Properties from this file are loaded on classpath and are made available to application like below--

```
List<String> argList = new ArrayList<>();
String properties = System.getenv().get("props");

try (InputStream is = BinaryFileReaderImpl.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(properties)) {
    if (is != null) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(is);
        for(String prop : props.stringPropertyNames()) {
            argList.add("--" + prop + "=" + props.getProperty(prop));
        }
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    //exception handling
}
```

This argList is passed to `SpringBootApplication` when it starts like below--

```
SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, argList);
```

I can access all the properties using `${prop.name}`

However, I do not have access to these properties when I run JUnit Integration Tests. All my DB properties are in this externalized properties file. I do not want to keep this file anywhere in the application eg. **src/main/resources**

Is there any way I can load these properties in spring's test context?

Comment: Have you tried the `@PropertySource` annotation on your tests?

Comment: Yes, I have tried `@PropertySource({"file:${props}")` as mentioned [here](https://blog.jayway.com/2014/02/16/spring-propertysource/). It has not worked on Windows. Haven't tried on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally read the externalized Properties file using `@PropertySource` on linux machine. Could not get it working on Windows instance though.

Changes done are as below-

```
export props=/path-to-file
```

Note that `file://` and actual file name has been removed from environment variable.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"file:${props}/file-test.properties", "classpath:some_other_file.properties"}) 
public class TestConfiguration {

}
```

Keep this configuration class in individual projects' src/test/java folder. Thank you [Joe Chiavaroli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9036108/joe-chiavaroli) for your comment above.

Comment: This worked on windows as well. For windows system variables to take effect, you need to restart your IDE / CMD.

Comment: I would use the following annotations `@TestConfiguration` and `@TestPropertySource`